# H.264 not streaming over dynamic DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting, video-streaming, h.264

I'm trying to view a network camera remotely so I registered with a dynamic DNS service. I can access the camera fine on the DNS associated URL and stream using MPEG but when I switch to H.264, the stream fails.

What's odd is I can stream H.264 if I use the local ip address. So the failure here is only occurring when streaming H.264 using the dynamic DNS address rather than the local ip.

I can't imagine why this would be. Would anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 3):

DNS is only responsible for resolving names to ip addresses. If you can access the camera via the name through HTTP/HTTPS and stream MPEG then it's not a DNS issue. DNS has resolved the name. If H.264 doesn't work then it's likely a firewall or configuration issue.

Comment: Would you know then if H.264 needs any additional ports other than the port used for HTTP or HTTPS?